# No logro cambiar las propiedades CSS de un elemento al ejecutar una función en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy tratando de intercambiar el color de dos divs cuando estos son pulsados, sin embargo la funcion se ejecuta correctamente pero el color sigue siendo el mismo en los dos elementos he probado de todo y nada funciona, pasa lo contrario a lo que intento hacer, es algo tan simple que no se que es lo que va mal, lo normal seria que me hubiera equivocado al escribir algo pero he revisado todo mil veces.

```js
let stableford = document.getElementById('stableford');
let scratch = document.getElementById('scratch');

scratch.addEventListener("click", setScratch => {
  scratch.style.background = "white";
  stableford.style.background = "grey";
});

scratch.addEventListener("click", setStableford => {
  stableford.style.background = "white";
  scratch.style.background = "grey";
});
```

```css
.modes {
    display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0 20px 0;
}
#scratch {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top: 12px;
  background: grey;
}
#stableford {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="modes">
  <div id="stableford">STABLEFORD NETO</div>
  <div id="scratch">SCRATCH</div>
</div>
```

Comment: y donde esta definida la función `setScratch`?

Comment: Se crea directamente, he provado tambien con funciones normales declarandolas antes y ocurre el mismo problema

Comment: en ambos casos escuchas al evento del mismo div -_-

Comment: Es verdad gracias no se como no lo he visto

Answer (score 1):

aqui la solución:

```
let stableford = document.getElementById('stableford');
let scratch = document.getElementById('scratch');

scratch.addEventListener('click', setScratch => {
  console.log('sisi');
  scratch.style.background = 'white';
  stableford.style.background = 'grey';
});

stableford.addEventListener('click', setStableford => {
  console.log('nono');
  stableford.style.background = 'white';
  scratch.style.background = 'grey';
});
```

el problemas es que en ambos escuchadores de eventos tenias scratch"

Comment: Muchas gracias, llevaba horas mirandolo y no se como no me habia dado cuenta